# Error: No pending request to flush !: How can I verify that $httpBackend is being used in jasmine unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test for a service that I have written that uses $http

I keep getting

```
No pending request to flush !
```

I have followed 2 or 3 examples and no matter what I change I keep getting that error. I even have a similar test that works except it is for a controller and not a service. (I know, $http shouldn't be in the controllers which is why I am trying a service now). I was wanting to know how I could check to make sure that the service is being injected with an $http service that has the $httpBackend mock in place?

I am using Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: Why $http shouldn't be in controllers?

Comment: Because I will have a couple of controllers that use the same method. So I put it in a service so that multiple controllers have access to it.

Comment: Can you paste your service code and your test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using angular 1.2rc2. You need to upgrade to 1.2.rc3 in particular you need to upgrade angular-mocks.js 1.2.rc3.

For what it is worth, this only occurs for services

```
Error: No pending request to flush !
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with the need to make the call to $http from within an $apply function, see: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2431#issuecomment-18566595

```
$rootScope.$apply($http.... );
```

Comment: No. Please see my answer.